# Makefile for multiple executables with folders

Tags: gcc, makefile

How do you create a Makefile that is concise in a project with multiple executables.
I tried learning directly from the Makefile documentation but it's overwhelming for me. 
This is an example of my project. I found questions that are related but they only have one executable and I'm interested in compiling all the different Unit-tests. I'm using gcc.

```
├── bin
├── include
│   ├── Action.h
│   ├── Consts.h
│   ├── Inventory.h
│   ├── Link.h
│   ├── Object.h
│   ├── Player.h
│   ├── Set.h
│   ├── Space.h
│   ├── World.h
│   └── WorldXMLReader.h
├── Mains
│   ├── Prototype.c
│   └── ... more source files with main()
├── obj
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── Set.o
│   └── ... more object files
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── Action.c
│   ├── Inventory.c
│   ├── Link.c
│   ├── Object.c
│   ├── Player.c
│   ├── Set.c
│   ├── Space.c
│   ├── World.c
│   └── WorldXMLReader.c
└── unitTests
    ├── UT_Inventory.c
    ├── UT_Link.c
    └── UT_Object.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a situation that is barely covered by most of the "make" tutorials: handling different sets of files in a generic way.

- Some files just provide  some implementation (lets call these "lib" files, even if they are not going to be compiled into a static or dynamic library file),
- other files hold a `main()` function and each of these must produce an executable binary, and links with the previous.

I won't here give you an all-finished makefile, but will try to show a global method on how to handle this situation.

So first, define the different source and object folders:

```
SRC_DIR_LIB=src
SRC_DIR_EXE=Mains    
OBJ_DIR_LIB=obj/lib
OBJ_DIR_EXE=obj/exe
BIN_DIR=bin
HEAD_DIR=include
```

(This is **very** useful because if one day the tree organisation changes, you will only have to edit the changes at a single point.)

And, yes, you should have separate folders for object files.

Then, define the sets of source files:

```
SRC_FILES_LIB = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR_LIB)/*.c)
SRC_FILES_EXE = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR_EXE)/*.c)
HEAD_FILES    = $(wildcard $(HEAD_DIR)/*.h)
```

Let make generate the set of object files:

```
OBJ_FILES_LIB = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR_LIB)/%.c,$(OBJ_DIR_LIB)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES_LIB))
OBJ_FILES_EXE = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR_EXE)/%.c,$(OBJ_DIR_EXE)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES_EXE))
```

Let make generate the set of executable files:

```
EXEC_FILES  = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR_EXE)/%.c,$(BIN_DIR)/%,$(SRC_FILES_EXE))
```

These will be your final target, you tell that to make with:

```
all: $(EXEC_FILES)
```

To make sure you have all these variables right, you can add a `show` target to your makefile:

```
show:
    @echo "SRC_FILES_LIB=$(SRC_FILES_LIB)"
    @echo "SRC_FILES_EXE=$(SRC_FILES_EXE)"
     .. and so on for all the others
```

Try a `make show`, and carefully check.

Then tell make how to do the real job. You need two separate compile targets:

```
$(OBJ_DIR_EXE)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR_EXE)/%.c $(HEAD_FILES)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<  $(CFLAGS)
$(OBJ_DIR_LIB)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR_LIB)/%.c $(HEAD_FILES)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<  $(CFLAGS)
```

**Edit**: use `$(CC)` for C programs, if it is C++, then use `$(CXX)`

And the linking step for the programs, that makes use of the `subst()` function:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%: $(OBJ_DIR_EXE)/%.o
    $(CC) -o $@ -s $(subst $(BIN_DIR)/,$(OBJ_DIR_EXE)/,$@).o $(OBJ_FILES_LIB) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Final comments:

- here, only basic dependency checking is done: any editing of **any** header file will result in a rebuild of **all** the files. This is not acceptable for a large project, but is ok for a small project as the one you describe.
- I did not here consider the "test" programs that need to be build here, but once you understand whats up here, it should not be difficult to handle these.
- I did not test this (instead, kinda copy'n'pasted from a makefile of my own, that was a C++ project), so there might be some minor changes left. Manual writing of makefiles is an art...

**Edit:** This is targeted for a Linux based environment, where program names usually have no extension. If Windows, you probably will need to add `.exe` at several places.