# Makefile does not work properly

Tags: makefile

I've this folder structure

```
project
|_src
| |_test
|   |_main.cpp
|_Makefile
```

This is my makefile (trying to adapt from [this link](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)):

```
CC = g++
RM = rm
WFLAGS = -c -Wall -W
LDFLAGS =
SRCTESTD = src/test
EXECUTABLE = test

OBJD = .obj
DEPD = .dep
SRCSTEST = $(SRCTESTD)/main.cpp
OBJECTSTEST = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJD)/test/%.o, $(notdir $(SRCSTEST)))
DEPDSTEST = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(DEPD)/test/%.d, $(notdir $(SRCSTEST)))

all: $(SRCSTEST) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTSTEST)
    $(CC)  $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTSTEST) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(WFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

It does not work, and I've this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `.obj/test/main.o', needed by `test'.  Stop.
```

What I'm doing wrong? Sorry for trivial question, but I'm a make newbie.

Comment: For your first makefile, you should try something much simpler.

Comment: I know, but it's for a work. I need to create these obj directories. I've also tried simpler makefiles and they work, so I've passed to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link shows outdated methods, such as [suffix rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html). Making dependencies can also be done during compilation by gcc/g++.

As for the rest, here is it :

```make
EXE         :=  test

SRCDIR      :=  src
OBJDIR      :=  .obj

SRC         :=  $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name "*.cpp")
OBJ         :=  $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEP         :=  $(OBJ:.o=.d)

LDLIBS      :=  # -l flags
LDFLAGS     :=  # -L flags

CPPFLAGS    :=  -MMD -MP # -I flags also
CXXFLAGS    :=  -W -Wall # no -c flag here

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

all:    $(EXE)

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(EXE)

re: fclean all

-include $(DEP)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:  $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

No redefinition of internally defined variables, no suffix rules, correct linking step and dependencies generation.

---

**Update**: To avoid calling `mkdir` for every source file, one should use [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) and the special target [`.SECONDEXPANSION`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html).

Change this block:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o:  $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

To this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp | $$(@D)/
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

%/:
    mkdir $*
```

Comment: Thanks. It give me an error at thie line: `$(RM) -r $(OBJDIR)` The error is `Makefile:21: *** missing separator.  Stop.` OBJDIR exists and I've also tried to change `-r` to `-fr`

Comment: StackOverflow automatically converts tabs into spaces, but Make needs tabs, so you have to fix this after a copy/paste.

Comment: @Jepessen If this answer or the other solved your problem, would you mind accepting it to close this question ?

Answer (score 2):

The error means make can't find a correct rule to build your object files. Your tree structure lacks some informations: only one file ? Where are the others ? Anyway, here are some hints:

In the last two lines, you are using an [obsolete feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) of make: suffix rules. I suggest you switch to a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules), which is functionaly equivalent.
Say something like:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Another thing (that shouldn't be a problem here): you are using the variable `CC` which is internally defined as the default C compiler. It's okay because you redefine it, but as your sources seem to be C++ files, why not use the variable `CXX`, that is [internally defined](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) as the C++ compiler ?

Lastly, to make sure your set of files are correctly defined, you can print them with a dummy `show` target, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23859765/193789).

```
show:
     @echo "OBJECTSTEST=$(OBJECTSTEST)"
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but the .o file is created inside `src/test`. I'd like to create all `.o` files inside the `.obj` folder in order to mantain clean my original folder structure. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, replace `%.o: %.cpp` by `$(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o: $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.cpp`, and define those variables.